# calculating a new column in Pandas using dictionary values and keys

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a data frame that contains a list of order `order_items` and their total price `order_price`.
The column `order_type` includes the order type: breakfast, lunch or dinner.

My goal is to confirm that that the given total `order_price` is correct. By multiplying the quantities (the second item in the tuple) by the item price. Then sum all the prices for one order and store it in a new column `order_price_checked`.

sample of my dataset:

```
    order_id    order_items                                                     order_type  order_price
0   ORDB10489   [('Coffee', 4), ('Salad', 10), ('Chicken', 8), ('Steak', 10)]   Lunch       1002.00
1   ORDZ00319   [('Fish&Chips', 9), ('Pasta', 5), ('Shrimp', 3)]                Dinner      614.50
2   ORDB00980   [('Pasta', 6), ('Fish&Chips', 10)]                              Dinner      515.00
3   ORDY10003   [('Chicken', 7), ('Steak', 1)]                                  Lunch       269.00
4   ORDK04121   [('Steak', 9), ('Chicken', 5)]                                  Lunch       565.00
5   ORDC10404   [('Burger', 3), ('Salad', 6), ('Fries', 7)]                     Lunch       280.20
6   ORDK05183   [('Chicken', 1), ('Steak', 10), ('Fries', 4), ('Salad', 6)]     Lunch       633.20
```

I have stored the prices for each `order_type` in a seperate dictionary.
For instance, `lunchDict` is for lunch orders.

```
{'Burger': 31.0, 'Fries': 12.0, 'Chicken': 32.0, 'Salad': 17.2, 'Steak': 45.0}
```

My approach is to match the first item in the tuple with the dictionary key. If it matches the key, then I will multiply the second item in the tuple (quantity) by the value of the corresponding key(price). 
Then obtain the total of all the orders and add it to a new column `order_price_checked`.

desired output(*I am only showing two columns to save space*):
for example index 1 and 4 show that we have wrong price.

```
     order_price   order_price_checked
   0    1002.00     1002.00
   1    614.50      600.20
   2    515.00      515.00
   3    269.00      269.00
   4    565.00      500.00
   5    280.20      280.20
   6    633.20      633.20
```

I tried to do it in a `for loop`:

```
for item in dirtyData['order_items']:
    for mytuple in item:
        if mytuple[0] in breakfastDict:
            tot=mytuple[1]*breakfastDict[mytuple[0]]
print(tot)
```

but this is not a clear approach and I can't tell which row I am working on.
Any input would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps its better if you provide pricing `dict` for Lunch or Dinner since your sample doesn't have breakfast :P

Comment: oh yeah! okay..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `.apply` on each row with a custom function to do the sum.

Example dataset (couldn't `pd.read_clipboard` yours because it has spaces; this is why it's better to give an example with code to create the dateset)
    import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['order_id','order_items','order_type', 'order_price'],
                  data=[
                      ('ORDB10489', [('Coffee', 4), ('Salad', 10), ('Chicken', 8), ('Steak', 10)], 'Lunch', 1002.00),
                      ('ORDZ00319', [('Fish&Chips', 9), ('Pasta', 5), ('Shrimp', 3)], 'Dinner', 614.50)
                 ])
```

setting up the dictionaries of prices, and a dictionary to map between meal types and their respective pricing dicts:

```
dinner_dict = {'Shrimp': 100, 'Pasta': 60, 'Fish&Chips': 14.5/9}
lunch_dict = {'Coffee': 33, 'Salad': 33, 'Chicken': 33, 'Steak': 10000}

meal_dict = {'Dinner': dinner_dict, 'Lunch': lunch_dict}
```

Defining the custom function (you could also do it with an inline `lambda` but it's clearer this way):

```
def sum_items_in_order(order, meal_dict):
    return sum(item[1]*meal_dict[order['order_type']][item[0]] for item in order['order_items'])
```

Your result would be as required:

```
df.apply(lambda order: sum_items_in_order(order, meal_dict), axis=1)
```

Comment: Good point on `pd.read_clipboard `. I will keep that in mind. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I like your question, so I took my lunch break to give it a try.
I assume you can choose your dataset format. I suggest you to keep them as lists.
Here is my own dataset based on yours.

```
 orders = [['ORDB10489',[('Coffee', 2), ('Salad', 2), ('Chicken', 1), ('Steak',    1)],'Lunch',40],
           ['ORDZ00319',[('Fish&Chips', 1), ('Pasta', 3), ('Shrimp', 2)],'Dinner',57.5],
           ['ORDB00980',[('Pasta', 4), ('Fish&Chips', 3)],'Dinner',50.5],
           ['ORDC10404',[('Burger', 1), ('Salad', 1), ('Coffee', 1)],'Lunch',18]]
```

The menu with prices:

```
 lunch = [['Coffee',2.00],['Salad',6.50],['Burger',8.00],['Chicken',10.00],['Steak',13.00]]
 dinner = [['Fish&Chips',7.50],['Pasta',7.00],['Shrimp',14.50]]
```

This is the a very simple code with variables' accesses based on the format item[i][j]. For example: [('Coffee', 2), ('Salad', 2), ('Chicken', 1), ('Steak', 1)]. It belongs to a sublist named order, then the 1st element is accessed by order[d][0], and the 2nd by the reference order[d][1]. So, order[0][0] is Coffee, order[1][0] is Salad, order[0][1] is 2 and order[2][1] is 1.

The code:

```
# reading all the orders, one by one    
for o in range(len(orders)):    
   order_id       = orders[o][0] 
   order          = orders[o][1]
   paid           = []  # empty list for every new order

   # reading all dishes, one by one 
   for d in range(len(order)): 
      dish      = order[d][0] 
      quantity  = order[d][1]
      service = orders[o][2] 

      if service == 'Lunch':
         for lu in range(len(lunch)):
             if dish == lunch[lu][0]:
                amount = quantity*(lunch[lu][1]) 
                paid.append(amount)
      else :
         for di in range(len(dinner)):
            if dish == dinner[di][0]:
                amount = quantity*(dinner[di][1])
                paid.append(amount) # adding to the paying list

due     = sum(paid) #sum of dishes in the list
bill    = orders[o][3]
print(order_id,due,bill)
```

The output:

```
ORDB10489 40.0 40
ORDZ00319 57.5 57.5
ORDB00980 50.5 50.5
ORDC10404 16.5 18
```

Comment: what a clean solution. Thank you!